# html page Redirect after certain amount of time to what he ask

Tags: redirect

how can I create HTML waiting page  for 10 seconds countdown, then transfer to the page requested  ( showthread.php )
for example somebody ask to download the below attachment file i need the guest or the member waiting some time then redirect to what he ask
http://shneler.com/vb/showthread.php?t=46900

Answer (score 0):

Edit: `setTimeout` returns immediately so that was totally wrong. This works though:

```
function displayTime(time, node) {
    if(time < 1) {
    window.location.href="https://wikipedia.org/";
  } else {
    node.textContent = time;
  }
}
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event){
  node = document.getElementById("time");
  var time = 10;
  setInterval(function(){time -= 1; displayTime(time, node);}, 1000);
});
```

You can even see it in action here: https://jsfiddle.net/perfectfire/n6cv5hvr/

Comment: If you're using a page whose sole responsibility is this countdown then just put it anywhere. In the `<head>` somewhere would make the most sense though.  You still need to design the page and get the node that you will write the countdown to.

Comment: anybody help me for this issue please ؟

Comment: Did you see the link I posted? It shows you everything you should do.

Comment: Thank you but i need more clarification I m not professional

Comment: @MohammadAhmadAlAjouri I answered your question with the exact implementation details you need to implement your desired functionality  and even provided a working example. What *exactly* more are you looking for?